# Xml with Xslt still don't work in Firefox 24

Tags: xml, xslt

This is .xml file, he is validate by a DTD document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./curric.xslt"?>
<!DOCTYPE radice SYSTEM "Curriculum.dtd">
<radice>
<curriculum>
 <dati>
  <nome>Luca</nome>
  <cognome>Rossi</cognome>
  <sesso>Maschile</sesso>
  <indirizzo>
    <via>Via Degli Angeli 35</via>
    <cap>21057</cap>
    <city>Olgiate Olona</city>
    <provincia>VA</provincia>
    <nazione>Italia</nazione>
   </indirizzo>
   <telefono>03313434322</telefono>
   <posta>rossi@mail.com</posta>
 </dati>
   <studi>
   <maturita>
    <titolo>Maturita' Scientifica</titolo>
    <voto>48/60</voto>
   </maturita>
   <laurea>
    <universita>Statale di Milano</universita>
    <facolta>Informatica</facolta>
    <votol>110</votol>
   </laurea>
  </studi>
  <esperienze>Da 3 anni responsabile tecnico "Inforscuola"</esperienze>
  <lingua>Inglese</lingua>
 </curriculum>
</radice>
```

and it is .xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HTML xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <BODY STYLE="font-family:Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22pt">
  <xsl:for-each select="radice/curriculum">
   <DIV STYLE="background-color:teal; color:white; margin-bottom:0.5em">
    <xsl:value-of select="dati/nome"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="dati/cognome"/>
   </DIV>
   <DIV STYLE="margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:1em; font-size:18pt;font-style:italic"> 
    Indirizzo: <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/via"/>
   <DIV STYLE="margin-left:100px;font-style:italic;font-size:18pt">
     <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/cap"/>
     <SPAN>
      <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/city"/>
     </SPAN>
     <SPAN>
      <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/provincia"/>
     </SPAN>
    </DIV>
    <DIV> Telefono:<xsl:value-of select="dati/telefono"/>
    </DIV> E-mail  :<xsl:value-of select="dati/posta"/>
   </DIV>
   <DIV STYLE=" font-size:24;font-style:verdana;color:black;background-color:#EEEEEE"> 
    Studi</DIV>
   <xsl:for-each select="studi/maturita">
    <DIV STYLE="font-style:arial; color:black;font-size:18pt;
     margin-top:1em;margin-left:20px"> 
     Media Superiore: <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
      <xsl:value-of select="titolo"/>
     </SPAN> - Voto  : <SPAN STYLE="color:teal"&g;>
      <xsl:value-of select="voto"/>
     </SPAN>
    </DIV>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:for-each select="studi/laurea">
    <DIV STYLE="font-style:arial; color:black;font-size:18pt; margin-left:20px"> 
     Universita': <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
      <xsl:value-of select="universita"/>
    </SPAN> - Corso di Laurea: <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
      <xsl:value-of select="facolta"/>
     </SPAN> - Voto  : <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
      <xsl:value-of select="votol"/>
     </SPAN>
    </DIV>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <DIV STYLE="background-color:#EEEEEE; color:black; margin-top:1em; font-size:24"> 
    Esperienze Lavorative </DIV>
   <DIV STYLE="font-style:italic; color:teal;font-size:18pt; 
    margin-top:0.5em; margin-left:20px">
    <xsl:value-of select="esperienze"/>
   </DIV>
   <DIV STYLE="background-color:#EEEEEE; color:black; margin-top:0.5em; font-size:24"> 
    Lingua Straniera </DIV>
   <DIV STYLE="font-style:italic; color:teal;font-size:18pt; margin-top:0.5em; 
    margin-bottom:2em; margin-left:20px">
    <xsl:value-of select="lingua"/>
   </DIV>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Files are in same directory in local and running .xml file on browser it say:"Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is update xslt file:

- you had bad begining of file
- no ending tags `</xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>`
- and `&g;` in `<SPAN STYLE="color:teal"&g;>` was making error too (not related to question)

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>

     <BODY STYLE="font-family:Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22pt">
      <xsl:for-each select="radice/curriculum">
       <DIV STYLE="background-color:teal; color:white; margin-bottom:0.5em">
        <xsl:value-of select="dati/nome"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="dati/cognome"/>
       </DIV>
       <DIV STYLE="margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:1em; font-size:18pt;font-style:italic"> 
        Indirizzo: <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/via"/>
       <DIV STYLE="margin-left:100px;font-style:italic;font-size:18pt">
         <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/cap"/>
         <SPAN>
          <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/city"/>
         </SPAN>
         <SPAN>
          <xsl:value-of select="dati/indirizzo/provincia"/>
         </SPAN>
        </DIV>
        <DIV> Telefono:<xsl:value-of select="dati/telefono"/>
        </DIV> E-mail  :<xsl:value-of select="dati/posta"/>
       </DIV>
       <DIV STYLE=" font-size:24;font-style:verdana;color:black;background-color:#EEEEEE"> 
        Studi</DIV>
       <xsl:for-each select="studi/maturita">
        <DIV STYLE="font-style:arial; color:black;font-size:18pt;
         margin-top:1em;margin-left:20px"> 
         Media Superiore: <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
          <xsl:value-of select="titolo"/>
         </SPAN> - Voto  : <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
          <xsl:value-of select="voto"/>
         </SPAN>
        </DIV>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:for-each select="studi/laurea">
        <DIV STYLE="font-style:arial; color:black;font-size:18pt; margin-left:20px"> 
         Universita': <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
          <xsl:value-of select="universita"/>
        </SPAN> - Corso di Laurea: <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
          <xsl:value-of select="facolta"/>
         </SPAN> - Voto  : <SPAN STYLE="color:teal">
          <xsl:value-of select="votol"/>
         </SPAN>
        </DIV>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <DIV STYLE="background-color:#EEEEEE; color:black; margin-top:1em; font-size:24"> 
        Esperienze Lavorative </DIV>
       <DIV STYLE="font-style:italic; color:teal;font-size:18pt; 
        margin-top:0.5em; margin-left:20px">
        <xsl:value-of select="esperienze"/>
       </DIV>
       <DIV STYLE="background-color:#EEEEEE; color:black; margin-top:0.5em; font-size:24"> 
        Lingua Straniera </DIV>
       <DIV STYLE="font-style:italic; color:teal;font-size:18pt; margin-top:0.5em; 
        margin-bottom:2em; margin-left:20px">
        <xsl:value-of select="lingua"/>
       </DIV>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </BODY>
    </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```